# How to put the column one-by-one to form the matrix in python

Tags: python

I have computed the column vectors for a matrix of this form Col1 | Col2 |...|Col_(m+1). But I do not know how to put together the column into a right order of the matrix. To combine the columns together, I google there are some methods using `vstack` or `hstack` in python which I am not familiar with. Is there a possible ways to put these together?

Let's say an example:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
b = np.array([0,2,3,5,1]) 
c = np.array([10,2,3,5,9])
```

Answer (score 1):

In `numpy`, you can use `np.dstack`

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
b = np.array([0,2,3,5,1]) 
c = np.array([10,2,3,5,9]) 

np.dstack((a,b,c))
```